# Is there a way to prove that I'm not in a simulation or a vr of some sorts in which everything I see, feel, etc aren't real?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mind, reality, solipsism, simulated-universe

My question is could all I think of as real in this world, the pain, the happiness, sadness all just be part of some futuristic vr of some sorts that is making me think i am thinking and doing all im doing in real life when actually im in a simulated world? Could all every person I think is real, everything I think im eating just be a simulation? In this certain world, I assume the only thing that actually exists is my conciosness. So in a way, this is in a sort of solipism. But can it be disproved?

Comment: You may read my answer in https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/48769/are-we-living-in-a-simulation-the-evidence

Comment: A proof is still unavailable but clearly it's pretty implausible that anyone could be conscious without having a body. If that was possible it's not clear what induces the brain of a bat to process bat-like perceptions instead of human-like perceptions. It's just an opinion, but I guess a lot of people would agree.

Answer (score -1):

## Because there is no way to tell that you are in a perfect simulation there is no way to tell that you are not in a perfect simulation.

There is no way to prove that you are in a perfect simulation that is exactly the same as reality, because this means that there is no discernible difference between the simulation and reality. If there is no discernible difference then there is no way to tell the difference because there is no difference to tell.

If the simulation is not perfect then it might leave tell-tale signs like the deja vu of the matrix trilogy.

> Since the brain in a vat gives and receives exactly the same impulses
>   as it would if it were in a skull, and since these are its only way of
>   interacting with its environment, then it is not possible to tell,
>   from the perspective of that brain, whether it is in a skull or a vat.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain_in_a_vat