# Is doubting inner world is like doubting external world?

Tags: skepticism, scepticism

Does scepticism of external world and sceptical on inner world of same level?

Like someone doubting external world doesn't exists, it is illusion or process or emergence by inner world, only inner world of mind and thoughts etc exists. And someone who doubting inner world of mind and thoughts etc like it doesn't exists, it is illusion or process or emergence by external world, only external world (or physical world) exists.

For example,

[PHYSICISTS ARE STARTING TO SUSPECT PHYSICAL REALITY IS AN ILLUSION](https://futurism.com/the-byte/physicists-suspect-reality-illusion)

Or scepticism about God's existence related to but distinct from external (physical) world.

Are both of scepticism has similar level of doubts, or of problem?

To clarify more,

Inner world of thoughts and feelings means, what we experience and feel from first person perspective. And sceptical of it, means being sceptical to claim that we are feeling something or we are really conscious or there is mental or first person feelings or experience.

Is there any special difference or both are same types of scepticism?

Comment: scepticism about God's existence and scepticism about the existence of external world are totally unrelated

Comment: God's existence is to give example of something completely different from physical world and of inner world of thoughts, etc.

Comment: "Same level" of what? Psychological anxiety?

Comment: @Conifold As some scepticism are different level from each other. Like scepticism about dark matter or scepticism about teapot orbiting Pluto are different level Or scepticism of moon or scepticism of free will are of different level.

Comment: Sure, there are different types of skepticism. But it is unclear according to what parameter you are proposing to compare them. What sort of answer about "levels" are you expecting?

Comment: Level may be inversely proportional to doubts. For example, to which we can almost absolutely sure, is at best level or maximum level. Like 'something exists'. And to which there is almost so much doubts or reason to doubts, which is absolutely no reasonable, it is at lowest or very low level.

Comment: I do not claim the objection is inescapable, but  which entity would be subject to this illusion in case mental reality would be illusory? I always wonder how mental reductionism does not at least try to answer this objection. For , of course from a third person point of view, I can try to reduce the others' mental states to physical states, but  can I make such an attempt for my own mental states?

Comment: Your wording could be clearer. "sceptical on inner world" solipsism? Philosophical zombies? You are asking about huge sprawling topics,  and then for a pretty arbitrary evaluatiin of 'same level'. What would that even mean? You might like this discussion 
 https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/48769/are-we-living-in-a-simulation-the-evidence

Answer (score 2):

James Conant has argued that skepticism about other minds and skepticism about the external world are of the same form - Cartesian. It's a lucid argument, and I think gets to what you're asking about. In case you can't access it the article is titled "Two Varieties of Skepticism."

https://humstatic.uchicago.edu/philosophy/conant/Conant%202012%20Two%20Varieties%20of%20Skepticism.pdf