# What is the best way to model reality if it is a simulation?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-physics, simulated-universe

Erwin Schrödinger proposed the quantum mechanical model of the atom, **which treats electrons as matter waves**.

So...

Quantum mechanics is a model, but it was not created on the assumption that the universe is a computer simulation.

What is the best way to model reality if we assume that it is a computer simulation?

In that case, we probably can not treats electrons as matter waves anymore.

How to interpret the Double-slit experiment if we assume that the world is a computer game?

Comment: *"In that case, we probably can not treats electrons as matter waves anymore."* Why not?

Comment: Exactly the way we currently model it: if reality is a simulation that "looks like" the way it looks like and we model what it looks like in the way that we model it, then nothing will change.

Comment: You might find these threads interesting https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/78382/simulation-argument-and-compressibility https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/48769/are-we-living-in-a-simulation-the-evidence There is a view that says quantum uncertainty is 'pixelation', but it's pretty naive because it's woven in to everything such as the existence of electron orbitals due to confinement around nuclei. Entanglement is the newer cause of perplexity that double slit behaviour was, but to say it's the simulation, is a 'god of the gaps' style argument.

Comment: "Best" for whom? The simulators themselves may model it like we model running programs on a computer, but since we can't tell what's behind the simulation curtain it would do us little good.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Modern games model classical physics. The OP is asking about the underlying quantum reality.

Comment: If what is a simulation? Reality or the model?

Comment: @CriglCragl  It may even be a rendering

Comment: @Sandejo Because it is a materialistic world view

Comment: @Conifold  "...but since we can't tell what's behind the simulation curtain.." This is exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: Trouble is, there is no point to looking for it. It is no more accessible to us than hardware to videogame characters.

Answer (score 0):

Quantum model only works for subatomic particles and not for very large astronomical bodies. Einstein tried to reconcile it with unified field theory and failed. But before deciding on how to simulate you would have to define reality.

Which definition of reality do you want to use?

Comment: I consider it as a computer game world.

Comment: that as such is not a definition which you could use for model parameters. computer games can be 2d 3d fixed weather dynamic weather you name it...