Do extreme coincidences have scientific meaning?
Let's say a 1 in a trillion world destroying asteroid is expected to hit on some important day (e.g. the inauguration of a president). Does the sheer weight of coincidences by itself provide evidence for design of the universe or is science still correct even if coincidences are extreme?
For example, The ratio between the mass of a typical human and the mass of the earth is avogadros number.

"Extreme" coincidences happen all the time, we just pay no attention to most of them. And they do not acquire "sheer weight" just because we consider them "important", physical events care not for human ideas of "importance".

The problem with "importance" of coincidence is that it is arbitrarily defined. So really almost anything can be made to have "importance", so we end up with nothing to count on.

There are so very, very many possible meaningless coincidences, that the fact that a few of them actually occur is usually just the workings of chance and nothing more.

An asteroid falling on Earth on the birthday of a president is not that unlikely. There are, after all only 365 days in a year. 0.25% of probability is unlikely but not infinitesimal. Even more so if we consider there are many presidents at a given time on earth. Please check the birthday paradox for an example of how poor is our instinctive understanding of coincidences and their probability.

@armand your comment implies that there is some sort of threshold below which it is now reasonable to believe that something is not coincidence. The probability being 0.0025% instead of 0.25% doesn’t give any more credence to the theory that “god did it”. Nothing that we know is possible should be given less weight than something with no existing evidence

@Syed it doesn't imply that. I'm just saying the example given by OP of a believability stretching coincidence is actually not that uncommon. I have sincerely no idea how you have read into it that a smaller probability implies divine intervention.

@armand Fair enough. After rereading your comment, I see where you’re coming from. I would like to say though that the probability of an event depends on how you frame the event. If you generalize an event enough and obscure its details, its probability approaches 1.

This question has emotional charge in the scientific world. It is like asking if Trump can make America great.
When you look at your personal life or at our reality, you will see the conclusive results where extreme coincidences have odds much lower than 1 in a trillion. Creation of a living cell or Theory of Evolution on a molecular level - are commonly used examples of the practical impossibility of random events (in the physical world) creating our reality.
But when you tell scientists that the chances of the precisely collected chemical building blocks (in the lab) assembling themselves into a living cell are similar to a tornado sweeping through the junkyard and building Ferrari in a process, it falls on deaf ears.

But if there is a vast cosmos of habitable planets, & life only occurred here, that's evidence toward concluding abiogenesis is very unlikely, but happened this once. Other 'explanations' like a preexisting intelligence raise more questions than they answer. Since the Miller-Urey experiment,scientists have been looking for solid evidence to constrain the probabilities around the beginning of life.

All I am saying is that both concepts of a naturally self-created physical world and intelligent design taking part in physical world creation are equally unprovable and should be treated accordingly.

That's not true. For instance quantum computing is being used on protein-folding, which could give much better data on likelihoods of processes for abiogenesis. Finding life elsewhere could be important too. Whereas ID is just religion.

@CriglCragl "but happened this once" - But that's begging the question; no one disputes that life exists on earth, but the question is about a reasonable explanation.  It is circular to assume that abiogenesis occurred on earth, as part of a probability calculation to conclude that abiogenesis is rare but occasional.

AFAIK the best guess for abiogenesis has the first kind of life being a kind that is long since extinct: something like free floating protein chains with self-replication and occasional heritable information-adding copy errors. Even primitive cells are a long way along on the hypothesized evolutionary arms-race - complicated machinery for isolating protein chains from other protein chains with a chemical tendency to break them down and turn them into more of themselves.

@PeterRankin: We await better data, as per 'Is the SETI project built on false premises?' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/100587/is-the-seti-project-built-on-false-premises/100595#100595

It falls on deaf hears because it's completely assinine.

In this case, biologists are talking about new proteins creation, which requires complexities not possible with random trial and error (mutation, selection).

Humans are really bad at imagining the time frames this planet existed for. A lot can happen in time frames like this.


Do extreme coincidences have scientific meaning?

I have this vacuum cleaner. I bought it brand new. The first time I switched it on the ground began shaking violently, dishes and glasses fell from the shelves. I finally came to my senses and shut off the vacuum and within a few seconds the ground stopped shaking.
What are the odds?! I can only conclude that my vacuum cleaner was responsible for the 2001 Nisqually earthquake.
I haven't used it since.
EDIT:
The relevant fallacies are:

Argument from Ignorance
Argument from Incredulity


Ooo, eloquent! I bow to a Master troll slicing Jedi.

Well, yes...
if the event is sufficiently unlikely, without an alternate explanation that would make it more likely, and...
if the event is sufficiently subjectively noteworthy, and...
if it cannot be explained by there being a large number of chances for events of similar subjective noteworthiness to take place.
The first condition (unlikelihood of the event) is self-explanatory.
The second condition means that if we flip a coin 20 times and get TTHHTHHHTHHHTHHTTTHH, we don't need to revise our hypotheses, because although the chance of this particular sequence was roughly 1 in 1 million, it wasn't noteworthy. If we flipped the coin 20 times and got HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH, this on the other hand is noteworthy despite having exactly the same probability as TTHHTHHHTHHHTHHTTTHH, and thus we may wish to revise a hypothesis about the coin.
The third condition means that if we flip a coin 20 million times, and at some point get HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH, we should not be surprised, because there were more than enough chances for a sequence as unlikely and noteworthy as that to occur. We shouldn't be surprised by TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT or THTHTHTHTHTHTHTHTHTH either, with that many flips.
Considering how many people are living in the world and how many different things they are constantly doing, there are a lot of chances for noteworthy coincidences. And so by the law of large numbers we should expect lots of noteworthy coincidences around the world, none of which give us any justified reason to change our hypotheses. So in general we should be skeptical that even quite big coincidences mean anything.
The example you give (a world destroying asteroid hitting on the US presidential inauguration day) would be very noteworthy. It's hard to imagine anything more noteworthy than a world destroying asteroid. And the US presidential inauguration day is also fairly noteworthy, though much less so than an asteroid. Most days of the year are noteworthy in the news for one reason or another. If not the inauguration, maybe it would have been the US presidential election day, or the day the election is called, or the day the electoral college convenes, or the election or inauguration day for some other major country, or the day of a presidential debate, or the g20 meeting, or the opening day of the Olympics, or Christmas, or the day someone announces a proof of the Riemann hypothesis, or... well, there are a lot of noteworthy days. So we wouldn't be justified in making any connection between the asteroid and the inauguration, since that connection (or one of similar noteworthiness) isn't particularly unlikely, assuming that the asteroid is going to hit on some day of the year.

The problem with the third condition is that what counts as "similar" is subjective. This leads me to think that your criteria is not adequate and faulty. Arguably, the only way for a coincidence to indicate something more profound is if a newer theory compresses the data in a better way than the currently accepted theory. Without this, there is no reason to think it is anything but coincidence. If there are multiple accepted theories explaining an outcome (such as a non designed card draw vs. cheating), one should use inductive experience to determine that.

To expand on the last sentence, what I mean by inductive experience is something like: most of the times we see a royal flush in history, we have noticed that it is cheating. Thus, it is reasonable to conclude cheating occurred rather than chance.

@Syed "If a newer theory compresses the data in a better way than the currently accepted theory" - yes, of course, this is the ideal Bayesian criterion. What I describe approximates it while being easier to estimate. It's a form of significance testing. "Notability" is the test statistic, and we reject the null hypothesis if the probability of observing events as notable or more notable than what was observed, is smaller than the significance level α.

the problem is that unless you know how a theory works and can outline how it explains certain data, there is no way to compress the data regardless of the improbability of the coincidence or whether it meets the conditions you outlined. A great example of this is the fine tuning of the universe. Even if you accept that the probability estimates of the fine tuned parameters are accurate, both god (and the multiverse theory, for that matter) do not compress the data in any known way. @causative

@Syed Well, that's changing the subject a bit. Not sure what the anthropic principle has to do with this kind of coincidences. The way that the anthropic principle might compress data is if specifying "this universe's parameters allow for intelligent life" is a more concise description than specifying the parameters directly. This would only compress data if it is possible to have a concise description of what "intelligent life" is. Which it might be.

Your post creates a thought event and asks about the consequences in case that the thought event becomes real.
Neither the thought event nor the case of its happening has any meaning for science: The trajectory of asteroids follows the rules of Newton’s mechanics. While the inauguration of a new US-president is a consequence of human decisions during the election. We have no evidence that both causal chains depend on each other, not at all.
The coincidence of two independent causal chains is best understood as a random event. Instead, to infer a hidden connection is superstition.

No.
When you say a "1 in a trillion world destroying asteroid" I take you to mean 1 in every trillion days (or something like that), such an asteroid will hit the Earth.
The fact that the impact coincides with other events has no significance. You posit that it happens to occur on the day of an inauguration. But there is nothing special to that. If it didn't happen on that inauguration day, it would just coincide with some other event.
No matter what day it happens to occur, that would not be evidence of design. It would only be evidence that more than one thing happens on the same day, which is unremarkable.

OP: "Let's say a 1 in a trillion world destroying asteroid is expected to hit on some important day"
It is a fair assumption that the OP intends that the asteroid event is causally unconnected to the important day event.  In other words, the OP is not claiming some space-pirates fired their asteroid cannon aiming to destroy the world on the aforementioned day.
The OP is suggesting the combination of the two rare events has special significance.  But is it scientifically meaningful?
In the quote below an example is given of two meaningfully connected events: In 1759 a fire broke out in Stockholm. At the same time, while at dinner 400km away with no possible means of communication Emanuel Swedenborg declared that a fire had broken out in Stockholm, (ref. Wikipedia).
There was apparently no scientific connection between the events, but the coincidence turned out to be highly meaningful for Swedenborg's dinner companions.
From The Interpretation of Nature and The Psyche by Carl Jung & Wolfgang Pauli, pp. 91-2.

If—and it seems plausible—the meaningful coincidence or
“cross-connection” of events cannot be explained causally, then the
connecting principle must lie in the equal significance of parallel
events; in other words, their tertium comparationis is meaning. We
are so accustomed to regard meaning as a psychic process or content
that it never enters our heads to suppose that it could also exist
outside the psyche. But we do know at least enough about the psyche
not to attribute to it any magical power, and still less can we
attribute any magical power to the conscious mind. If, therefore, we
entertain the hypothesis that one and the same (transcendental)
meaning might manifest itself simultaneously in the human psyche and
in the arrangement of an external and independent event, we at once
come into conflict with the conventional scientific and
epistemological views. We have to remind ourselves over and over again
of the merely statistical validity of natural laws and of the effect
of the statistical method in eliminating all unusual occurrences, if
we want to lend an ear to such an hypothesis. The great difficulty is
that we have absolutely no scientific means of proving the existence
of an objective meaning which is not just a psychic product. We are,
however, driven to some such assumption unless we want to regress to a
magical causality and ascribe to the psyche a power that far exceeds its empirical range of action. In that case we should have to suppose,
if we don’t want to let causality go, either that Swedenborg’s
unconscious staged the Stockholm fire, or conversely that the
objective event activated in some quite inconceivable manner the
corresponding images in Swedenborg’s brain. In either case we come up
against the unanswerable question of transmission discussed above. It
is of course entirely a matter of subjective opinion which hypothesis
is felt to make more sense. Nor does tradition help us much in
choosing between magical causality and transcendental meaning, because
on the one hand the primitive mentality has always explained
synchronicity as magical causality right down to our own day, and on
the other hand philosophy assumed a secret correspondence or
meaningful connection between natural events until well into the
eighteenth century. I prefer the latter hypothesis because it does
not, like the first, conflict with the empirical concept of causality,
and can count as a principle sui generis. That obliges us, not
indeed to correct the principles of natural explanation as hitherto
understood, but at least to add to their number, an operation which
only the most cogent reasons could justify.

So if the meaningfulness of the coincidence(s) is persuasive enough the observer may be persuaded to add to their natural repertoire an acausal facility.
This is the usual way that things are deemed to exist, according to Kant note 36 B287:

"[existence] is the conjunction of the [notional] thing with perception."

and at A598/B626:

"In the logical use [existence] is merely the copula of a judgment."

That is, the judgement in connecting the evidence of the senses with an idea in mind.
Note however, Buddha advocated an extreme parsimoniousness of such judgements:

"Concerning the seen, the heard and the cognized he does not form the
least notion. That brahmana who does not grasp at a view, with what
could he be identified in the world?"

Sutta Nipata 4.5, 'Paramatthaka Sutta: On Views'

"If—and it seems plausible—the meaningful coincidence or “cross-connection” of events cannot be explained causally, then the connecting principle must lie in the equal significance of parallel events; in other words, their tertium comparationis is meaning".. The thing is that there is no fixed, unique way to assign meaning, even for the same person. Anyway, nice references, upvoted.

Your title question seems different from the body so I’ll answer the body.
Can an extreme coincidence indicate design of the universe? Presumably, you are referring to god. If so, the question can be rephrased as: can an extreme coincidence indicate God’s existence?
If so, then it would only indicate evidence for God’s existence/design if the probability of God existing and choosing to design that coincidence is higher than the probability of that event occurring by chance.
There are two problems with this: a) probability is inherently subjective. The sample space of outcomes depends on you, not the universe. In the universe, things just happen and there is only one timeline of events. Probability is based upon possibility and you can imagine many different kinds of possibilities according to many different models.
b), and this is still related to a), almost (if not every) event can be construed to have an infinitesimally low probability. For example, suppose you toss 100 coins. The particular sequence that it would result in has a probability of (1/2)^100. This is much, much lower than 1 in a trillion. And yet, is this evidence of god somehow influencing your mind to toss that sequence? No. Why not? Because you have no reason and no apriori evidence to suggest that a) a designer exists and b) that He would have the desire to cause you to toss that specific sequence.
In conclusion, if your question is in reference to supernatural design, the answer would be no.

If you cannot describe even in a far-fetched way random events creating our physical world, then you should not be so confident about your 'no'.

@TheMatrixEquation-balance first of all, who said random events created our physical world? Secondly, can you describe how exactly this supposed god exists and creates this world apart from saying “god did it”? If you can’t, I wouldn’t be so confident of a designer


Presumably, you are referring to god. === No! He's talking about sufficiently advanced technology that is indistinguishable from magic.


@Miss_Understands I can’t tell whether you’re being sarcastic or not, but if you’re not, the same applies. If there’s no evidence for an advanced technology that is indistinguishable from magic, then one can dismiss it, regardless of whether one can disprove it. We do this all the time subconsciously when we eliminate an infinite number of needless theories that “fit” the data but explain nothing in our heads. P.S. I read your blog once. - An adrenaline junkie with a nerdy side (who isn’t an incel)

No. Unlikely coincidences happen every day, they don't prove anything.
In general, you can't make conclusions from coincidences after the fact. If, on the other hand, someone predicted this event, that would be evidence that they knew something about the universe. If it's an astronomer who studied the orbit of the asteroid, it just demonstrates that our understanding of orbital mechanics is correct. But if it came from an ancient religious text, it could be considered evidence of the truth of that text.
Some have claimed that Nostradamus had supernatural powers of prediction by showing that many of his prophecies have come true. But they were written in such vague, poetic forms that it's not hard to pick some event and find a prophecy that you can interpret to refer to it -- he never named names.
Another area where people use ex post facto arguments to "prove" things is numerology. They find arbitrary numerical coincidences, and assert that they have important significance.
In the scientific method, we start with a hypothesis, use it to make predictions, then perform experiments (or make observations when crafted experiments are not feasible, e.g. astronomy); if the results are consistent with the predictions, it adds credence to the hypoethesis. Conclusions from coincidences are missing the step of confirming the hypoethsis.
