What is the strongest argument to debunk Bostrom’s Simulation Hypothesis?

Are we living in a computer simulation? Are we just a video game being
played by some snot-noised kid on Alpha Centauri? This idea, or family
of ideas, is known as The Simulation Hypothesis and it has been
gaining more and more traction since philosopher Nick Bostrom wrote
his 2003 paper “Are You Living in a Computer Simulation?

Bostrom’s Simulation Argument argues for the truth of one of three
propositions:
i. Almost all civilizations go extinct before
technological maturity.
ii. All civilizations lose interest in
advanced computer simulations.
iii. We are almost certainly living in
a computer simulation.  If neither i. or ii. is plausible or probable,
then we are left with iii.

How do we end up with iii.? Well, in supporting iii., Bostrom explains
that his argument is different than any other skeptical threat in the
history of philosophy because instead of starting from a position of
universal doubt and saying “prove that we can know anything”, the
Simulation Argument starts from exactly what we know right now and
asks us to reason a bit down the time line which leads us right into
iii.


All you have to do is follow our trajectory down the line and it’s not
too hard to imagine that one day we will create a simulation of our
ancestors for any number of reasons including to run various scenarios
and learn about our history, to review different outcomes and find out
what went wrong and when, or even just for entertainment- a
seven-billion-person reality show.


If the argument is cogent thus far, then it follows that if the
advanced civilization is capable of running these types of computer
simulations with self-conscious persons like us in them, then they
would run lots of them over and over for whatever reasons they wanted.

Here goes the debunking argument (it did not convince me):

Anderson, in Plantingian fashion, deals the final blow as he argues
that the Hypothesis is actually self-defeating,
“The simulation hypothesis itself is based on scientific theories and
concepts derived from our experiences of the world. It is predicated,
at least in part, on what we take to be empirical scientific knowledge
(what brains are and do, what computers are and do, etc.). But if we
accept the simulation hypothesis then we acquire a defeater for all of
our empirical beliefs and thus for all of our scientific beliefs.
Simply put, if the simulation hypothesis is true, we can’t trust the
science on which the simulation hypothesis is based, in which case it
would be irrational to believe the simulation hypothesis. It looks
like the simulation hypothesis has a deeply self-defeating character
to it.”

https://thethink.institute/articles/simulation-theory-debunked

@andrós - If you don't care, they will not let you play poker. This is why they give you pain, so you should care.

Just like solipsism, Boltzmann brains or the existence of philosophical zombies, the main rebuttal is there is no actual reason to believe in the simulation hypothesis. Is there any observed phenomenon around you that would be better explained by the simulation hypothesis than by the "we leave in a real world" hypothesis? Reality around us seems pretty consistent and doubt it for the sake of doubt is unproductive. In order to doubt healthily you first need reasons to doubt.

Your source, Parker's Pensées, lists several criticisms and even Wikipedia has pages more. Are we supposed to read your mind over the internet to decide which you would find the "strongest"? Your post does not even mention what it was that did not convince you, let alone any criteria of "strength" that would make this anything other than opinion magnet.

"Are we living in a computer simulation?" "We" should include all of us, including the simulators. In which case the question is simply nonsensical.

This question is similar to: What are some arguments against the brain-in-a-vat thought experiment?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

(And also https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/48769/are-we-living-in-a-simulation-the-evidence is similar)

Do we not need also 4) All advanced civilizations would spin up large quantities of simulations of universes before stopping to think if they should.

You might like this thread: 'Are we living in a simulation? The evidence' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/48769/are-we-living-in-a-simulation-the-evidence
